# python 3 scatter plot gives "ValueError: Masked arrays must be 1-D" even though i am not using any masked array

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter

I am trying to plot a scatter plot using the .scatter method below. Here

`ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c = colors, marker = 'o', s=80, edgecolors = 'none')`

with the input/args classes below:

`X[:,0]] type:  <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
X[:,1]] type:  <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
colors type:  <class 'list'>`

however python is throwing a value error as seen here:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGG61.png)

Comment: could you try to print out the shapes of the arrays?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put the thing in brackets:

```
plt.scatter([X[:,0]],[X[:,1]])
```

Comment: Can you explain why this happens and why this fixes it?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian see my answer for a possible explanation

Answer (score 9):

My experience with this is because your `X` is a numpy `matrix`.

Essentially, whenever you try and isolate a row from a matrix, it returns another matrix. Numpy seems to have a constraint that matrices *must* be 2 dimensional, so it can't tell that it's a 1-d array, and can't mask it (hence the `Masked arrays must be 1-D` error)

The solution for me was to simply "cast" `X` to a `numpy.array` by doing:

```
X = np.array(X)
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c = colors, marker = 'o', s=80, edgecolors = 'none')
```

Comment: This fixed my issue when I encountered the same error message, thanks!

Comment: It also works when reduced to a list using numpy's tolist() function as in:  X[:,0].tolist()